# Joomla: passing array of items in REST get method

Tags: php, joomla3.0, restful-url

I am writing a RESTFul service for the mobile application. My REST url is follows:

```
/index.php/jbackend/get/recipe/list_recipe?id=3,4,5
```

where, 3,4,5 are the recipeids.

in the joomla code, I have the following to parse:

```
    $ids = $app->input->get('id', array(), 'ARRAY');
    $i=0;
    foreach($ids as $id){
        $i+=1;
        $response['array'.$i] = $id;
    }
```

I get the respose as

```
{"array1":"4,5,6"}
```

I expect as

```
{"status":"ok","array1":"4","array2":"5","array3":"6"}
```

To get the above, what needs to be changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found one way like below:

pass the parameter as

1. Get

   /index.php/jbackend/get/recipe/list_recipe?id[]=3&id[]=4&id[]=5
2. Post

   /index.php/jbackend/get/recipe/list_recipe
   and the parameters as post arguments.

hope this helps for others.